# How to turn multiple rows corresponding with one ID into single row - Presto

Tags: presto

I'm looking the way to convert the data below

```
"itemid"        "attr_id"        "Merk"        "Berat"        "Panjang"        "BPOM"        "TInggi"        "Kadaluarsa"
3624918424        14718        "Hansaplast"        ""            ""              ""            ""        ""
3624918424        22229             ""             ""            ""              ""            ""         "24 Bulan"
```

into this one

```
itemid  Merk    Berat   Panjang BPOM    TInggi  Kadaluarsa
3624918424  Hansaplast                  24 Bulan
```

I have checked another questions in SO, the most popular answer is by using PIVOT function. but that function didnt exist in presto. can someone have solution using presto?

Comment: Kadaluarsa has two entries, how do you decide which entry to pick? First one?

Comment: Hi @PhilippJohannis thanks for responding. I have revised the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just work with `GROUP BY` clause to get the desired result:

```sql
SELECT itemid
,MAX(Merk) Merk
,MAX(Berat) Berat
,MAX(Panjang) Panjang
,MAX(BPOM) BPOM
,MAX(TInggi) TInggi
,MAX(Kadaluarsa) Kadaluarsa
from data_table
GROUP BY itemid
```

It's not clear in your example if the columns are `NULL` or have an empty string `''` - with an empty string it might be a bit more complicated and you need something like for all columns:

```sql
,MAX(case when Merk='' then NULL else Merk end) Merk
```

If you have multiple entries per itemid and you want to keep all entries you can also work with [`array_agg`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html):

> **array_agg(x) → array<[same as input]>**
> Returns an array created from the input x elements.